# Braided or stranded tinned copper for flexible connection?

Tags: power, batteries, current, dc, wire

I need a series connection between sets of batteries dealing with around 120A at 52V peak in an electric longboard. I expect the highest flex will be around 45 degrees, but mostly less than 20.

I think I have two options (please correct if wrong); I can use flat tinned copper braid in heat shrink or standard silicone stranded copper wire. Ignoring the height advantage of the copper braid, what other pros/cons are there for each choice in terms of current, wear due to flex, etc?

Comment: Imho for the same amount of copper, the more strands the better

Comment: That is  6.2 kW. Assuming 85% efficiency, that is an output power of 5.27 kW or 7 HP. That is ridiculous for a longboard. You won't even be able to stand on it. It is also more power than any commercial longboard on the market. So, I call BS on your specifications. But I agree with PlasmaHH.

Comment: :| I did say peak and the silliest reason for the power system to fail would be to have a wire melt. For the record, I plan on having two of [these babies](http://alienpowersystem.com/shop/brushless-motors/aps8072s-sensored-bldc-motor-165kv-6000w/), and thats not even as far as you can go. [I've seen 4wd electric mountainboards that draw a lot more power.](https://www.electric-skateboard.builders/t/4wd-heavy-duty-offroad-monster-board-vesc-c6364-sensored-12s30ah-10kw/20783).

Comment: In regards to having more power than any commercial longboard, what do you think the point of building your own is? :D

Comment: You don't need 7HP. Your battery pack cannot deliver 7 HP. You don't want 7HP. You are not going to get 7HP. By all means experiment and build your board and have fun. It is cool to build stuff and play with it. That is how we learn. But designing for 120A and 52V is not realistic. Can your battery pack even deliver 120A?

Comment: Yes, yes it can. I'm building a pack with 72 18650 30Qs, each can sustain 20A. In a 12s6p configuration at full charge thats 52V at 120A. Of course it's unlikely to ever draw that much, but it seems a good starting point for finding the required current carrying capacity of the wiring.

Comment: That will be a monster battery pack. Hope you know what you are doing. But at full charge that is 50.4V, not 52. I still don't think you want or will get 7hp. It is too much power. The highest power boards available already have enough acceleration so that it is nearly impossible to stay on the board at full throttle, and 7hp would leave them in the dust like a ferrari vs a VW bus.

Answer (score 1):

Two types of braid available: tubular and flat.  Look at wire mfr. datasheet for equivalent AWG or cross section area to determine ampacity.

When you mention flexing, is that primarily in only one axis?  If you need flexibility in two axes then tubular braid might be a better choice.

For single axis bending and torsional bending, flat braid works well.